# Count with respect to a particular attribute

Tags: python

Say I have something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Obj   = namedtuple('Obj', ['x', 'y']) 
items = [Obj(1,1), Obj(1,2), Obj(1,3), Obj(1,3), Obj(1,3)]
```

Is there a way to `count` with respect to a specific attribute? I was hoping you might be able to do something like:

```
test  = [ obj for obj in items if items.count(obj.y) > 1 ]
```

This, however, gives an empty list, rather than a list containing the element `Obj(1,3)`. Does anyone have a one line solution?

Comment: `objs.count(obj.y)` will *always* be zero - e.g .`3` isn't in `objs`, `Obj(1,3)` is

Comment: Your input data doesn't vary the `x` attribute. Should `Obj(2, 3)` be counted for the `3` attribute?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a mapping of counts, separately; using [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) makes this easy enough:

```
from collections import Counter

y_counts = Counter(obj.y for obj in items)
test = [obj for obj in items if y_counts[obj.y] > 1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Obj   = namedtuple('Obj', ['x', 'y']) 
>>> items = [Obj(1,1), Obj(1,2), Obj(1,3), Obj(1,3), Obj(1,3)]
>>> y_counts = Counter(obj.y for obj in items)
>>> [obj for obj in items if y_counts[obj.y] > 1]
[Obj(x=1, y=3), Obj(x=1, y=3), Obj(x=1, y=3)]
```

Comment: gah! beat me to it :) had the almost exact same answer.

Comment: @zsquare: but with a crucial difference; count `obj.y` occurrences, not the objects themselves.

Comment: yeah, just read the comment which said that `Obj(2, 3)` should be counted.

Answer (score 1):

To get all objects `obj` from `items` where `obj.y` appears more than once in the list, in one line:

```
test = [obj for obj in items if sum(1 for o in items if o.y == obj.y) >  1]
```

This gives me:

```
[Obj(x=1, y=3), Obj(x=1, y=3), Obj(x=1, y=3)]
```

However, note that this "algorithm" is `O(n**2)`, which isn't very efficient. Instead, make a dictionary (you can simplify this with `collections.defaultdict(list)`):

```
d = {}
for obj in items:
    if obj.y not in d:
        d[obj.y] = []
    d[obj.y].append(obj)
```

Then get the values which are longer than one:

```
test = []
for v in d.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        test.extend(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, is collect the items that have the number of objects with the same value of y

A simple way to do it would be,

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(items)
```

and then, your required test,

```
test = [obj for obj, count in counter.items() if count > 1]
```

Comment: This counts the *wrong thing*. `Obj(2, 3)` should be included with the other `obj.y == 3` items.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, because [Martijn Pieters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24139949/3652183) is clearly much better and easier. The thing is that `count` relies on the `__eq__` function, so you can override it to achieve the result.

```
from collections import namedtuple 

class CustomTuple(namedtuple('Obj', ['x', 'y'])):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.y == other.y
```

Then you can use:

```
items = [CustomTuple(1,1), CustomTuple(1,2), CustomTuple(1,3), CustomTuple(1,3), CustomTuple(1,3)]
print [obj for obj in items if items.count(obj) > 1]
```

Or directly:

```
[obj for obj, count in Counter(items).iteritems() if count > 1]
```

Basically you're just saying that `CustomTuple('value', y)` is always equal to `CustomTuple('another_value', y).` for all `y`.