# Python Counter: print key whose count is x

Tags: python

Say I have a `Counter` object representing a collection of words:

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'world']
>>> counter = Counter(words)
```

One way to find out which words have count 1 would be to iterate over `counter`:

```
for word, count in counter.items():
    if count == 1:
        print(word)
```

Is there an easier/better way to do this? That is, can one "invert" `counter` to give the word whose count is `x`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reverse any mapping—whether a `Counter`, a `dict`, or anything else:

```
rev = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
```

Then you use that like any other dictionary:

```
key_whose_count_is_10 = rev[10]
```

---

In the case where there are two keys with the same value, the value will map to one of them, arbitrarily. But that's pretty much inherent in your problem. You're asking for "the" key whose count is `x`; what do you want to do if there are three keys whose count is `x`?

---

If you're only going to be making one query, rather than multiple queries, it's more efficient to just iterate. Which one is *clearer* (which is almost always more important) is arguable. Here's one way to do it, for comparison:

```
key_whose_count_is_10 = next(k for k, v in d.items() if v==10)
```

Comment: yes this is a good answer. to handle multiple keys, one could return a list.

Comment: @gjdanis: Sure, although I think a `set` might be even better. (Not so much for performance—unless you have tons of dups that isn't going to matter—but just because it better gets across the idea that there's a set of keys with equal values, with no particular order among them.)

Answer (score 5):

It would be far better to put every element with value 1 in a list, I think. Here's a Pythonic way to do this:

```
new_list = [w for w in words if counter[w] == 1]
```

Like this, you will store every word in `words` that has value of 1 in your counter.

So, for example, if you have in your list another string, say the string `test`:

```
words = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'world', 'test']
```

then, the new list will have the values `world` and `test`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Counter` object uses each word as the key and stores the number of occurrences as the value.

To do what you want to do, you need to use the number of occurrences as the key and the list of words as the value:

```
wordDict = {}
for word, count in counter.items():
    if count in wordDict:
        wordDict[count].append(word)
    else:
        wordDict[count] = [word]
```

Then you can use `wordDict[2]` to grab the list of words that appear twice.

Comment: This is just a clunkier and more verbose version of Simeon Visser's answer.

Comment: @abarnert When I started writing up my answer there were 0 answers posted. Now there are 6... and I was just about to delete my answer but it was upvoted as I was writing this sentence... good grief. I guess it doesn't hurt to have a verbose version to really show what's going on... at least it's more beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to check each element's count

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'hello', 'hi', 'hi', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(words)
>>> [i for i in counter if counter[i] == 1]
['world', 'bar', 'foo']
```

You can also use the `count()` function on the original list

```
>>> [i for i in words if words.count(i) == 1]
['world', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: I just feel like I [should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139817/count-with-respect-to-a-particular-attribute) use it :)

Comment: This turns a linear algorithm into a quadratic one for no good reason. (For each word in words, you're searching all the words in words.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word, count in counter.items():
    d[count].append(word)
```

You can then do:

```
d[1]
```

to get all words with count one (as there can be one or more words).

Comment: This is overcomplicating things.

Comment: Can we do it without defining another data structure, though?

Comment: @abarnert: how exactly is this overcomplicating? It inverts the counter as asked and you can lookup the words by count.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: If he asked for "the key whose count is x", he's going to have to do `d[count][0]` to get that, instead of just `d[count]`. And getting an `IndexError` on `0` instead of a `KeyError` on `count` will be less meaningful during debugging. (Plus, it will create a new entry in `d`.)

Answer (score 0):

Using filter (or ifilter if itertools is imported)

```
n = 1
for word in filter(lambda w: counter[w] == n, words):
  print word
```

Comment: Better to use a comprehension than a `filter` call when you have an expression (like `counter[x[0]] == n`) instead of a function, because with `filter` you have to wrap the expression in a function, which is more verbose, easier to get wrong, and slower.

Comment: I agree, just providing a different approach. Improved answer to iterate over words rather than counter